# Expand / Collapse Product description tabs

Tags: magento2, tabs

I want to implement dynamism i-e expand/collapse in product description tabs at mobile view as shown in the figure.

[image: I want if somebody click on the description tab it should expand and collapse at mobile view]

I want if somebody click on the details tab it should expand and collapse at mobile view

Answer (score 0):

It's already collapsible on mobile view you have to just add up and down arrow by using some css

Comment: It has already up and down arrow. But the arrows are not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your less like this:

```
.product{
&.detailed{
    .items{
        .title{
            &:after{
                content:'down-arrow';
            }
            &.active{
                &:after{
                    content:'up-arrow';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}